# Spring Boot and Postgresql application fails at build in docker due to not available Postgresql instance

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a Spring Boot application that I want to be built and run in docker environment.

My docker file look like following:

```
FROM maven:3.6.0-jdk-11-slim AS Build
COPY src /home/app/src
COPY pom.xml /home/app
RUN mvn -f /home/app/pom.xml clean package -Pdocker

#
# Package stage
#
FROM openjdk:11-jre-slim
COPY --from=Build /home/app/target/academy*.jar /usr/local/lib/academy.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-Dspring.profiles.active=docker", "-jar","/usr/local/lib/academy.jar"]
```

My docker-compose file look is like following:

```
version: "3"
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:13
    network_mode: bridge
    container_name: postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    expose:
    - 5432
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
         - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=docker
         - POSTGRES_USER=docker
         - POSTGRES_DB=academy
    restart: unless-stopped
# This is my rest api app*****************************************
  academy:
    build:
      context: ../IdeaProjects/academy
    image: academy:1.0
    network_mode: bridge
    container_name: academy
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    expose:
      - 8081
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    volumes:
          - /home/pramod/Desktop:/var/tmp
    restart: unless-stopped
volumes:
  postgres-data:
```

When I run docker-compose build, it fails with error

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.determineDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:100) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:137) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    ... 17 common frames omitted
```

Is there a possibility to start postgresql database before it builds image for spring app?

Comment: The image build sequence can never call another container, even if it's running.  Why do you need the database running to create a .jar file?

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/ - There is a script in there that will wait until postgres is ready before your app starts. However I would try and run your app manually after you are sure postgres has started as I think that error is something else, check the errors or logs above the one you pasted as it may be helpful.

Comment: This error is generated by unit tests. So  I had to disable unit tests that are run during build phase.